# What is the disk strategy of HDFS datanode when it has multiple disks and block directories?

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

For example, I have two disks /dev/sda, /dev/sdb,

**The mapping of device and the block directories** are as follow

```
/dev/sda   /data/1/dns/dn
/dev/sdb   /data/2/dns/dn
```

**The conditions** are `/data/1/dns/dn` has 10M space, `/data/2/dns/dn` has 400GB.

My question about the strategy of HDFS are:

- Should these two directories store different blocks of HDFS file?
- The space of `/data/1/dns/dn` is obviously small, will HDFS detect that and write the block into the bigger one?

Answer (score 0):

I found the two algorithms exist in the configuration of HDFS datanode:

- Round robin
- Available space

My choice is round robin, it seems when the disk space is small, the `available space` algorithm still applied.